# Infinite dice game

Tags: probability-distributions, infinity

Would a game of infinite dice each wjth infinite sides produce a bell curve when outcomes are plotted against time?

I assume that there still remains a higher probability of  outcomes from the middle of the infinite set of possibilities leading to a normal curve

Comment: You will need to specify the probability of each face of your infinite-sided die: you cannot have a "fair" die with infinitely many sides.  Once you specify the probability of the faces, you can then determine the distribution of sums (which I assume is what you mean by "outcomes").

Comment: The probability of any one face would be infinitely small.  The die would appear to be a perfect sphere with each resting point being a face. Is this fair or not is the question.  Because if it is fair then we should see a normal distribution of sums.  If it is not fair  then no pattern would emerge.  I wonder if there would still be a higher proportion of sums occurring in the mid range of an infinite set

Comment: "Infinitely small" is not a number.  A probability must be a number.  You cannot have an infinite-sided die with equal face probabilities since the sum of all the face probabilities must be one, and if the face probability is non-zero, then the sum is infinite.

Comment: If you take a perfect sphere as a die then the chance of it resting on each of what are indeed infinite sides is 1 but would take an infinite  length of time to achieve of course

Comment: I guess that each point is a coordinate of three numbers rather than one number

Comment: You cannot assign a distinct positive integer to each point of a sphere (since there are uncountably many points on the sphere), so you cannot make a die as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

An "infinite dice" as you say can be easily modelled by the "rand" (random) function (results between 0 and 1) you have even on pocket computers. No need to have a "bump" in the center. The bump will appear when you add $n$ times the results, and it will look gaussian, even when $n=5$, as in the simulation below (on a hundred thousand throws of 5 "dices") where the results are dispersed  between $0$ and $5$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  But you have set a boundary between 0 and 1 for an infinite set of real numbers.  This i can see must result in a gausian curve. What if the set of outcomes is unbounded though